# Can't boot to OSX on 2013 Macbook Air after installing Windows 8

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, partition

I installed Windows 8 using the Bootcamp today. During the partition screen when installing Windows 8, there was no NTFS partition. There was one partition which said Bootcamp on it. I formatted it and selected it for Windows installation. Everything went well and Windows is installed.

But now I am unable to boot into my OSX. Every time I start my Mac it directly goes to Windows.

Is there anyway I can get OSX back? I do need Windows though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried holding down the option key when you reboot? You can also select the default boot disk from the bootcamp GUI in windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Holding the option key worked. I just din think of that.